# How to jump to function definition in .ml (not .mli) in emacs merlin-mode

Tags: emacs, ocaml, merlin

When I press `M-.` or `C-c C-l` it usually jumps to the function's declaration in *.mli* file. Oftentimes there is associated *.ml* file to which I can switch with `C-c C-a` but then, I have to search for the implementation of this function in it manually.

If there is an easy way to either jump directly to a definition in *.ml* file or somehow position to the corresponding function location when switching between *.mli* and *.ml*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is governed by the `merlin-locate-preference` variable, which documentation says:

> Determine whether locate should in priority look in ml or mli files.

So you will land to the implementation, if it is available, once the variable is set to `'ml`:

```
(setq merlin-locate-preference 'ml)
```

It is interesting though, that it defaults to `'ml` so that either you overwrote it or merlin jumps to mli because it can't find the definition. If you want to jump to the definition in another project, then add corresponding `S` and `B` clauses to your `.merlin` file.